Why is my image hosted on Imgur not loading on some mobile devices?
Clearly explain your issue, for example:
I’m working on a project in plain HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I use an image hosted on Imgur (https://i.imgur.com/JiwDusX.jpeg) as the background for a canvas.
The image loads fine on desktop browsers and some mobile devices.
However, it fails to load on certain phones (e.g., iPhones or specific Android devices).
Problem encountered:
When the image doesn’t load, it doesn’t appear at all. There are no specific error messages in the browser console.
Hypotheses:
It could be a compatibility issue with Imgur hosting.
It might be related to CORS restrictions or the image format.
Describe what you’ve already tried, for example:
Checked the image URL directly in mobile browsers:
It works fine on desktops but inconsistently on some phones.
Added crossOrigin = "Anonymous" when loading the image in JavaScript, but the issue persists.
Tested different browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.), but the results vary.
Expected result:
I expected the image to load correctly on all devices.
app on live: https://forex-flyer.vercel.app/
load image function
---javascript
async loadFlyerBase() {
                try {
                    const flyerUrlJpg = 'https://i.imgur.com/JiwDusX.jpeg';
                    const flyerUrlWebP = '/forex.webp';
                    
                    // Détection support WebP
                    const isWebPSupported = this.isWebPSupported();
                    const flyerUrl = isWebPSupported ? flyerUrlWebP : flyerUrlJpg;
                    
                    // Tentative de récupération depuis le cache
                    if ('caches' in window) {
                        const cache = await caches.open('flyer-cache-v2');
                        let cachedResponse = await cache.match(flyerUrl);
                        
                        if (!cachedResponse) {
                            await cache.add(flyerUrl);
                            cachedResponse = await cache.match(flyerUrl);
                        }
                        
                        if (cachedResponse) {
                            const blob = await cachedResponse.blob();
                            this.flyerBase = await this.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                        }
                    }

                    // Si pas de cache, chargement direct
                    if (!this.flyerBase) {
                        this.flyerBase = await this.loadImage(flyerUrl);
                    }

                    await this.renderFlyer();
                    this.showProgress(100);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Erreur chargement base:', error);
                    this.showMessage('Erreur lors du chargement du modèle', 'error');
                    throw error;
                }
            }

            // Méthode de détection WebP
            isWebPSupported() {
                try {
                    return document.createElement('canvas')
                        .toDataURL('image/webp')
                        .indexOf('data:image/webp') === 0;
                } catch(err) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            loadImage(src) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const img = new Image();
                    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
                    img.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Chargement image échoué: ${src}`));
                    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
                    img.src = src;
                });
            }

            async handleImageUpload(event) {
                const file = event.target.files[0];
                if (!file) return;

                // Validation du format
                const validTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/webp'];
                if (!validTypes.includes(file.type)) {
                    this.showMessage('Format non supporté. Utilisez JPG, PNG ou WebP', 'error');
                    return;
                }

                // Validation de la taille
                if (file.size > 10 * 1024 * 1024) {
                    this.showMessage('Image trop volumineuse (max 10 Mo)', 'error');
                    return;
                }

                this.loadingOverlay.style.display = 'flex';
                this.showProgress(0);

                try {
                    // Compression de l'image avant traitement
                    const compressedFile = await this.compressImage(file);
                    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(compressedFile);
                    
                    this.cropperImage.onload = () => {
                        this.previewPlaceholder.style.display = 'none';
                        this.cropperImage.style.display = 'block';

                        if (this.cropper) {
                            this.cropper.destroy();
                        }

                        // Configuration du cropper
                        this.cropper = new Cropper(this.cropperImage, {
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            viewMode: 2,
                            dragMode: 'move',
                            autoCropArea: 0.8,
                            restore: false,
                            guides: true,
                            center: true,
                            highlight: false,
                            cropBoxMovable: true,
                            cropBoxResizable: true,
                            toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
                            minContainerWidth: 250,
                            minContainerHeight: 250,
                        });

                        this.cropBtn.disabled = false;
                        this.loadingOverlay.style.display = 'none';
                        this.showMessage('Image chargée avec succès', 'success');
                    };

                    this.cropperImage.src = imageUrl;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Erreur traitement image:', error);
                    this.showMessage('Erreur lors du traitement de l\'image', 'error');
                    this.loadingOverlay.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }


When I access https://i.imgur.com/JiwDusX.jpeg directly in my browser via the address bar, it redirects me to https://imgur.com/JiwDusX - which is an HTML document, and will of course not work as a (background) image. They probably do this based on specific request headers send by the client.

You are simply trying to use this platform for something it isn't intended to be used for. https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/26516761846171-I-can-t-see-the-images: "We allow hotlinking on forums, but these images cannot be used as content for a website, including blog posts, avatars, site elements, and advertising."
